# VB.NET Datagrid / Datatable column decimal formating

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, formatting

I have got a data column representing integer values for example
value 100000, i would like to format display into 100.000 or 100 000. To fix this i used code below but seems it doesn't work in my case.

dt.Rows(i).Item("QORDPO") = FormatNumber(ilosc, 0,,, TriState.True)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DataGridView (as the tags indicate) have you tried the DefaultCell Property on the column?  There are various option one of which is Custom, if the ones presented don't suit.

[image]

Examples of setting the column format properties in code:

```
datagridview.Columns("aColumn").DefaultCellStyle.Format() = "C" '--- currency
datagridview.Columns("aColumn").DefaultCellStyle.Format() = "N1" '--- number 
datagridview.Columns("aColumn").DefaultCellStyle.Format() = "d" '--- date
```

Comment: Nope i have custom source so im not able to edit with editor

Comment: The property can always be set in code, I added some lines.  Lots of info on the net on the how to format in vb.net.  Example on how to format numbers here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings